# Higher-order reduce() function

Tags: javascript, reduce, higher-order-functions

I want to abstract the function that gets passed into my arrays' `reduce()` functions to make the function a generic 'greatest of the Array reducer'. To achieve this, I want to then pass in different specific functions in the `reduce()` parameters to be able to specify the criteria for comparison. In my example, these are the lines

`return players.reduce(topPlayerReducer, players[0], getThreePointerPercentage);`

and

`return players.reduce(topPlayerReducer, players[0], getReboundNumber);`

where `topPlayerReducer` is a generic function passed to `reduce()` that finds the biggest item in an array based on some criteria. My criteria are the 3rd arguments. How can I incorporate my specific comparison functions (`getThreePointerPercentage` and `getReboundNumber`) so that I keep this level of abstraction? Right now, I'm getting the error that `fn` is not a function in `topPlayerReducer`. I'm not surprised by this, because my other functions aren't within the scope. I've also tried doing

`var reboundReducer = topPlayerReducer.bind(getReboundNumber);`

```
return gameInfo.players.reduce(reboundReducer, players[0]);}
```

but I've gotten the same error.

I realize I can achieve a result with making two different functions for `reduce()`, but that doesn't satisfy me. I want to know if there is a way to do it differently.

```
function getGuardWithMostThreePointers(gameInfo){
    return players.reduce(topPlayerReducer, players[0], getThreePointerPercentage);
}

function getPlayerWithMostRebounds(gameInfo){
    return players.reduce(topPlayerReducer, players[0], getReboundNumber);
}

function topPlayerReducer(topPlayer, currentPlayer, fn){
    if (fn(currentPlayer) > fn(topPlayer)){
        return currentPlayer;
    } else {
        return topRebounder;
    }
}

function getReboundNumber(player){
    return parseInt(player.rebounds_offensive) + parseInt(player.rebounds_defensive);
}

function getThreePointerPercentage(player){
    return parseInt(player.three_pointers_made) / parseInt(player.three_pointers_attempted);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like so:

Change the implementation of `topPlayerReducer` so that it returns a function which compares two players, rather than comparing the players itself:

```
function topPlayerReducer(fn){
    return function(topPlayer, currentPlayer) {
        if (fn(currentPlayer) > fn(topPlayer)){
            return currentPlayer;
        } else {
            return topPlayer;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `reduce` like so:

```
return pointGuards.reduce(topPlayerReducer(getThreePointerPercentage), pointGuards[0]);
```

or

```
return gameInfo.players.reduce(topPlayerReducer(getReboundNumber), gameInfo.players[0]);
```

This way you can pass in a custom function with each different call you make to `reduce`, you just 'wrap it up' in `topPlayerReducer` first. I think this is what you were trying to achieve with `bind`.

---

FYI: I think what you were looking for from `bind` is something called *partial application*, where you take a function with multiple arguments, supply some but not all of the arguments, and get back a function which expects the remaining arguments. 
You can do this with `bind`, but you have to remember:

1. that bind takes an extra argument which is bound to `this` within the function,
2. that the arguments you are 'pre-loading' will fill in from the *left*.

So your attempt to use bind would have worked if you'd made these changes:

```
// Make fn the leftmost parameter
function topPlayerReducer(fn, topPlayer, currentPlayer){
    if (fn(currentPlayer) > fn(topPlayer)){
        return currentPlayer;
    } else {
        return topRebounder;
    }
}

// Add an extra 'null' argument to be bound to the `this` variable
return players.reduce(topPlayerReducer.bind(null, getReboundNumber), players[0])
```

For my money, the `bind` version just adds clutter in this situation. `bind` can be useful when you have functions which make use of `this`, though, and you need a way to change its value.

Comment: That worked! It's a little hard to believe how it works, but I think I got it.

Comment: Cool. Basically, with the new implementation, each time you call `topPlayerReducer` it returns a brand new function that takes two players and returns the one who satisfies the criterion. A function which you create this way is just the same as one you define directly, so you can pass it into `reduce` and all that good stuff.

If you want to get your head around it a bit more, try fiddling with `topPlayerReducer` a bit: call `var foo = topPlayerReducer(someFunc)` at the command line/console. Then you can see what `foo` is, try calling it with some arguments, etc.